# linking information in two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I am typing this on behalf of a friend, so this may be worded badly:

I have two tables `interests` and `user_updates`:

```
$feed_query = mysql_query("SELECT `username`, `contents`, (`posted`) AS posted FROM 
    user_updates ORDER BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`posted`) DESC");
$num_rows = 0;
while(($num_rows < 12) && ($row = mysql_fetch_array($feed_query))){
```

This is the code getting the information from the `interests` table, but I want to easily get the corresponding data (The correct update) from `user_updates`

how can i go about doing this?

Comment: if you're trying to limit the number of rows fetched, consider using a `LIMIT` clause in the query itself, rather than counting in php.

Comment: Before you develop some kind of chronic dependency on the creaky, antiquated `mysql_query` interface, you should spend the small amount of time required to learn PDO or `mysqli`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to join two tables on a common field :

table names : user_updates and interests

common field username (Common field must have the same values on each table, so that they can be matched against each other)

```
select * from user_updates u 
     inner join interests i
on i.username = u.username
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a join statement. Check the MySQL documentation for more: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you out:

```
<?php
$feed_query = mysql_query("SELECT upd.username,upd.contents, (upd.posted) AS posted FROM user_updates upd LEFT OUTER JOIN interests int ON int.id=upd.interest_id  ORDER BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(upd posted) DESC"); 
$num_rows = 0; 
while(($num_rows < 12) && ($row = mysql_fetch_array($feed_query))){

    echo $row['username']."---".$row['contents']."---".$row['posted']."<br>";

    $num_rows++;
}
?>
```

Comment: This is indeed a "correct" response (well, maybe, we don't know exactly which columns he wants to get) but I'm hesistant to upvote because @mobile clearly has no idea what joins are in the first place. Dumping a full solution on him won't help him much in learning how to use joins in the future.

Comment: You are right sgroves, the information is not clear. But at least it's a close idea... I like to see straight questions and straight answers as well...